# Is it possible to keep the JqGrid code in an external javascript file and reference the file in the HTML page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

The following JqGrid script works fine in the HTML page (I am using asp.net MVC). But if I move it to external javascript file the controller action does not fire and the JqGrid is empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#main_list").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsList", "Home")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Load', 'Customer', 'Container'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'Load_ID', index: 'Load_ID', width: 100, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'Customer_Name', index: 'Customer_Name', width: 100, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'Container', index: 'Container', width: 100, align: 'left' }],
            jsonReader: {
                rows: 'rows',
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: 'Load_ID'
            },
            pager: jQuery('#pager_main_list'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 600,
            caption: 'Loads'
        });
    });

</script>
```

When the HTML page loads the JqGrid is populated with data.

I moved this to an external javascript file called `home.js` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#main_list").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsList", "Home")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Load', 'Customer', 'Container'],
        colModel: [
          { name: 'Load_ID', index: 'Load_ID', width: 100, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Customer_Name', index: 'Customer_Name', width: 100, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Container', index: 'Container', width: 100, align: 'left' }],
        jsonReader: {
            rows: 'rows',
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: 'Load_ID'
        },
        pager: jQuery('#pager_main_list'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 600,
        caption: 'Loads'
    });
});
```

and the reference to the external javascript file in my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/home.js")"></script>
```

Now when the HTML page loads the JqGrid is empty. What should I do to trigger the controller's action while the page is loading?

Comment: Hint `url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsList", "Home")',`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please explain? I have this "url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsList", "Home")'," in my code already

Comment: That gets replaced by the serverside, when you move it to the external file, it is not going to be replaced.